# Сохранение результата response (axios) в глобальной переменной

Tags: javascript, axios

HTML:

```
<button type='button' id='btn1'>
<button type='button' id='btn2'>
```

JS:

```
let name;
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  axios.post('/someUrl', {
      name: 'someName'
    })
      .then((response) => {
        name = response.data.name;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    // здесь return? 
});

const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(name)
});
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
let resource = '';
 const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
 const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

 btn1.addEventListener('click', () => {

axios.post('/someUrl', {name: 'someName'})

  .then((response) => {
    resource = response.data;
  })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

 });


  btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log(resource)
  });
```